# How do I get Firefox to animate the opacity of links within SVG text elements using jQuery?

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg, jquery-animate

The desired effect for this code is to have the word 'hello' change opacity at a different time to the word 'world'. This works correctly in all major browsers except Firefox (Mac and PC - it works fine on Firefox iOS app). In Firefox, the words 'hello' and 'world' become visible at the same time.

Any help very much appreciated, thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('svg').delay(0).fadeIn(1000);
    $('#hello').delay(800).animate({
      opacity: "0.80"
    }, 1100);
    $('#world').delay(1100).animate({
      opacity: "0.80"
    }, 1750);

  });
```

```css
svg {
  fill: black;

}
#hello,
#world {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <text x="50%" y="78%">
    <a id='hello'>Hello </a>
    <a id='world'>world</a>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `opacity`, use `fill-opacity` instead

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('svg').delay(0).fadeIn(1000);
  $('#hello').delay(800).animate({
    fillOpacity: "0.80"
  }, 1100);
  $('#world').delay(1100).animate({
    fillOpacity: "0.80"
  }, 1750);

});
```

```css
svg {
  fill: black;
}
#hello,
#world {
  fill-opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <text x="50%" y="78%">
    <a id='hello'>Hello </a>
    <a id='world'>world</a>
  </text>
</svg>
```